# Can I compile a single aspx.cs file into a DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to make a single small update to a website written in C#/ASP.NET.

All I'm trying to do is change the email address a form submits to, which is why I'm not seeking out a proper C#/ASP.NET developer.

I've done a little research, and it seems that the site itself is using `dll` files in the `/bin` folder to run the forms and things. The form is `contact.aspx.f3293f9sd.dll`, so I've edited the corresponding `contact.aspx.cs` file.

What do I do now?

Can I build this single `CS` file into a single `DLL` and upload it? I've scoured the menus and see no such option, and Google results seems to imply that you need to add entire projects and build entire projects at once.

Is that correct? What's the process here?

Comment: You can try compiling on the command line.  In general when making a change to the production system one *should* perform a full deployment and not just pick-and-choose components.  This is useful for a number of reasons, including deployment automation (to reduce human error) as well as testing and validation (the code deployed is the same code that was tested).  In the future it's also recommended not to hard-code values like email addresses and instead include them in a configuration file so they can be modified without re-building the code.

Comment: what is the project type output this is where you would select output type = `ClassLibrary` this is not that trivial.. keep in mind that all the project files will be compiled into a single .dll.

Comment: Use the config file for an email change.

Comment: Assuming the email is a company email address, you could just set that email address up to forward to something else and leave it all alone.

Comment: @David Your suggestion about not hard-coding things is noted, but unfortunately, that's not how my workplace's old contractor built the site. I attempted to build on the command line but ran into a 'type or namespace VAIRef could not be found', is that a consequence of picking and choosing? Unfortunately I can't work out how to build the entire thing.

Comment: @GreenTriangle: Regardless of how the code was originally written, it should certainly be *corrected* to use a config value instead of hard-coding. From the compiler error, it sounds like that page depends on things outside of that page. In that case, no, the page by itself can't be independently compiled. As for building the whole thing, well, if you can't build/deploy your application then you don't have much ownership over it. Either the contractor failed to deliver on something or the company failed to retain the deliverable. You're going to want to be able to compile your application.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is open the solution file. Solution files are files composed of projects. The `contact.aspx.cs` file is part of one of those projects. You need to make your change in the file, then recompile your solution. Then you can upload the DLL file it outputs to your production. Make sure you compile in Release mode.

Comment: I don't have any `.sln` files, if that's the correct file extension. Am I out of luck if so?